# Iterate through the parameters for a method

Tags: java, function, parameters

I have a few variables in my POJO class like:

```
variable01String
variable02String
variable03String
variables01int
variables02int
variables02int
```

method to call

```
performMethod(variable01String, variables01int)
```

I want to call the performMethod for

```
performMethod(variable01String, variables01int)
performMethod(variable02String, variables02int)
performMethod(variable03String, variables03int)
```

I am wondering if we can just call **performMethod(variable01String, variables01int)** and increment the number **01** that is there in between the name of the variable s0 that I can save a few lines of the code.

I do have up to **12** variables with like the above scenario.
**Note:** I cannot change the names of the variables in the POJO class.

I know I can use an Array but I have close to 50 variables in my POJO class. So, I am thinking if there is an different way to do this than Array

Comment: You should use an array instead.

Answer (score 0):

Put your variables in an array an then iterate over the indices.

```
String[] stringVariables = { variable01String, variable02String, variable03String };
int[] intVariables = { variables01int, variables02int, variables03int };
for (int i = 0; i < stringVariables.length; i++) {
  performMethod(stringVariables[i], intVariables[i]);
}
```

Comment: Hi, I want to know if we can do in any different way than Array because my POJO is really big.

Comment: @Vamsi Your POJO won't be very big if you use an array instead of redundant variables.

Comment: @shmsoel True, I just cannot change the POJO as I am instructed to use the existing POJO with all the 50 variables

Comment: @Vamsi Then your only other option would be using reflection. I wouldn't recommend it unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: @shmosel oh. I will try having a look at it then. Thanks.